# Most beautiful checkmates?

Tags: checkmate, famous-games, famous-moves

What is the most beautiful checkmate you've ever seen in high-level play? The beauty might be caused by one of the following:

- A brilliant setup (the couple moves preceding the mate were brilliant)
- Totally unexpected/against the odds (for example, the other opponnent was up a lot of material)
- Swiftness (of course no fool's mate or such)
- etc.

Comment: Hi OmnipresentAbsence, I closed this question because it's asking for opinions as opposed to an answer.  The [FAQ](http://chess.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) has some more information, and there is a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) about how you can sometimes ask a subjective question in a constructive way.

Comment: [this collection](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1022764) contains all of my favorite games I have seen.

Comment: You don't see a lot checkmates at high level of play as players resign before a mate can be delivered.

Comment: @Akavall Of course, pretty stupid of me

Comment: Anybody asking this question is bound to appreciate many [games of Gyula Breyer](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessplayer?pid=11063) if not familiar with his contributions to the modern game. A serious pity he died at only 28. IMO, some real beauty in his works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the list of *Immortal* games listed here :http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1000589

Especially enjoyed Paul Morphy vs Duke Karl : http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1233404

and Lev Polugaevsky vs Rashid Gibiatovich Nezhmetdinov (this is simply stunning): http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1111459

Answer (score 4):

I don't really see too many high level games that end in checkmate, especially beautiful checkmates, but this game is one of my personal favorites, although White resigned:

`Lev Polugaevsky vs Rashid Gibiatovich Nezhmetdinov`

`Sochi 28th RSFSR ch 1958  ·  Old Indian Defense: Ukrainian Variation (A54)  ·  0-1`

```
[FEN ""]
1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 d6 3. Nc3 e5 4. e4 exd4 5. Qxd4 Nc6 6. Qd2 g6 7. b3 Bg7 8. Bb2 O-O 9. Bd3 Ng4 10. Nge2 Qh4 11. Ng3 Nge5 12. O-O f5 13. f3 Bh6 14. Qd1 f4 15. Nge2 g5 16. Nd5 g4 17. g3 fxg3 18. hxg3 Qh3 19. f4 Be6 20. Bc2 Rf7 21. Kf2 Qh2 22. Ke3 Bxd5 23. cxd5 Nb4 24. Rh1 Rxf4 25. Rxh2 Rf3 26. Kd4 Bg7 27. a4 c5 28. dxc6 bxc6 29. Bd3 Nexd3 30. Kc4 d5 31. exd5 cxd5 32. Kb5 Rb8 33. Ka5 Nc6
```